# EntityFramework: Using EntityTypeConfiguration to map a class that has a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I have this class:

```
public class RecentlyViewedProducts : BaseEntity
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<int> ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

How to use [`EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType>.HasKey<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671266(v=vs.113).aspx) method to say that the generated table will have a composite key `(CustomerId, ProductId )`?

That means I want to get the "rows per customer" as the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) of the related `List`?

Comment: I improved the title, the question and added two links to relevant MSDN resources.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in the second question. entity.ProductId.Count?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a composite key by including this in your mapping:

```
// Primary Key
HasKey(e => new { e.CustomerId, e.ProductId});
```